# Freezing haproxy traffic with maxconn 0 and keepalive connections

Tags: http, load-balancing, haproxy, keep-alive

Since `haproxy v1.5.0` it was possible to temporarily stop reverse-proxying traffic to frontends using

```
set maxconn frontend <frontend_name> 0
```

command.

I've noticed that if haproxy is configured to maintain keepalive connections between haproxy and a client then said connections will continue be served whereas the new ones will continue awaiting for "un-pausing" a frontend.

The question is: is it possible to terminate current keepalive connections *gracefully* so that a client was required to establish new connections?

I've only found `shutdown session` and `shutdown sessions` commands but they are obviously not graceful at all.

The purpose of all of this is to make some changes on server seamlessly, otherwise in current configuration it would require a scheduled maintenance window.

Comment: Please vote for moving it to serverfault